# I want access local file using file reader?

Tags: reactjs

```
getImage(file) {
let context = this;
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
  return function(e) {
    context.setState({
      images: e.target.result,
    });
  };
})(file);
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

}

Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: what is `theFile`? and what is the type of `theFile` in your `onload`?

Comment: it is the image file. type is jpg. file is (c://xampp/htdocs/media/image.jpg)

Comment: Please, write to console file value then send console image

Answer (score 0):

Files that comes from a `<input />` of type *file* are stored in an array form.
If `GetImage` is the callback of the onChange event of your `<input />` you need to extract it in the following form:

```
function getImage(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];

  // ...code

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```